# Can Core i7 1165g7 laptop run with DDR4 2666Mhz RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory

I bought a Dell Inspiron 5502 laptop with 11th gen rocket lake Core i7 1165g7 and 12GB of ram.

The specifications for the CPU an laptop say it's compatible with DDR4 3200Mhz ram.

I want to upgrade it to 32GB of ram but I'm having trouble finding compatible and affordable 3200Mhz ram sticks. There a lot of affordable 2666Mhz DDR4 kits, I could even afford 64GB 2666Mhz ram for the price of the few 32GB 3200Mhz kits I've found.

Should that laptop and/or CPU work with 2666Mhz ram? Is 3200Mhz the max supported speed but lower speeds are also supported or is that the **only** supported speed?

Comment: Lower speeds are indeed supported

Answer (score 0):

While it's *possible* to mix RAM with differing speed, [it's not recommended](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/07/what-are-the-rules-on-mixing-two-different-types-of-ram/). In any event, if you keep your exiting 3.2 GHz RAM and combined it with 2.7 GHz RAM, the system could run no faster than the slower sticks.

1. Are you really maxing out 12 GB of RAM?
2. If you add more RAM, but at slower speed, would that actually improve things?

Comment: Hello, I don't plan to mix them, I want to replace the original 12GB (8GB + 2GB at 3200Mhz) with 2 x 16GB at 2666Mhz if possible. 

1. Yes, I need more than 12GB. I need to run multiple virtual machines simultaneously.
2. Yes, having more RAM available for the VMs even if a little slower improves things vs having less faster ram.

Comment: That should be safe... but check Crucial, https://www.crucial.com/products/memory/memory-buying-guide , or Kingston, https://www.kingston.com/us/memory , for ther compatibility checks.

Answer (score -1):

Hope your doing well. Yes, the i7-1165G7 can support 2666 MHz. The laptop I am typing this on is actually a i7-1165G7 with 2666 MHz, and have proof if you'd like. Also just made this account to answer your question, so if I don't see your reply immediately I apologize but will not forget about the post, and will check again.